Accessing a colour without specifying a list of definecolor
I would like to declare a number of colour palette names and then define only those colours at the beginning of a document.  For instance, one can define a colour palette variant is optimized for users with blue-yellow color deficiency (tritanopia).  And for other conditions as well.  Rather than having a separate package for each, I would like to only use one style file.
Have started with the following set of colours.  Would it be possible to have a command that provides a specific colour by specifying the string name such as red-warmer or red-intense, which I can then use for my text.  Which would spare me from defining a multitude of colours such as below.
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\RequirePackage{xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Nn \colortext:nn
  {
    \begingroup
      \IfValueTF{#1}
        {
          \IfStrEq {#1} {red}         {\definecolor{tempcolor}{HTML}{a60000}}{}
          \IfStrEq {#1} {red-warmer}  {\definecolor{tempcolor}{HTML}{972500}}{}
          \IfStrEq {#1} {red-cooler}  {\definecolor{tempcolor}{HTML}{a0132f}}{}
          \IfStrEq {#1} {red-faint}   {\definecolor{tempcolor}{HTML}{7f0000}}{}
          \IfStrEq {#1} {red-intense} {\definecolor{tempcolor}{HTML}{d00000}}{}
          \textcolor {tempcolor} {#2}
        }
          {
            \definecolor {tempcolor} {HTML} {d00000}
            \textcolor {tempcolor} {#2}
          }
    \endgroup
  }

\NewDocumentCommand {\colortext} { O{red-intense} m }
  {
    \colortext:nn {#1} {#2}
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\colortext {Some coloured text}

\end{document}


I am not sure to understand. Why don't you define the color globally and then use simply \textcolor commands? Or either, use the mix ability like red!90!black or similar things.

Because I want to have different colour schemes for accessibility (deuteranopia, tritanopia) and do not want to define so many colours.  Because only a few will acually be used.

How many more accounts will it take until you add MWE to your questions?

you are using far more code avoiding defining colours than the color definition would use. \IfStrEq {#1} {red-warmer}  {\definecolor{tempcolor}{HTML}{972500}}{}  makes no sense at all, simply use globally \definecolor{red-warmer}{HTML}{972500}   and then directly use #1 of your command as a color name,

But then I would end up with the definition of many colours as I would same with yellow, blue, green, magenta, cyan, etc .

@Bulldrive yes but stored and accessed efficiently rather than inefficiently in a linear search of string comparisons.

\IfValueTF{#1}
        {
          \IfStrEq {#1} {red}         {\definecolor{tempcolor}{HTML}{a60000}}{}
          \IfStrEq {#1} {red-warmer}  {\definecolor{tempcolor}{HTML}{972500}}{}
          \IfStrEq {#1} {red-cooler}  {\definecolor{tempcolor}{HTML}{a0132f}}{}
          \IfStrEq {#1} {red-faint}   {\definecolor{tempcolor}{HTML}{7f0000}}{}
          \IfStrEq {#1} {red-intense} {\definecolor{tempcolor}{HTML}{d00000}}{}
          \textcolor {tempcolor} {#2}
        }

Is implementing a slow and inefficient lookup of something that the \color command would look up directly using the hashed command names that TeX implements. Just define the colors globally and use them in your command.
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\definecolor{red}{HTML}{a60000}% or a new name such as `red-standard`
\definecolor{red-warmer}{HTML}{972500}
\definecolor{red-cooler}{HTML}{a0132f}
\definecolor{red-faint}{HTML}{7f0000}
\definecolor{red-intense}{HTML}{d00000}

\NewDocumentCommand {\colortext} { O{red-intense} m }
  {
    \textcolor{#1} {#2}
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\colortext {Some coloured text}

\end{document}


Could I define some palette names and then define only those colours at the beginning of a document.  For instance, one can define a colour palette variant is optimized for users with blue-yellow color deficiency (tritanopia).

yes put a bunch of \definecolor commands in tritanopia.sty and then use \usepackage{tritanopia} and that set will be defined (or similar variants on that)  That is exactly what the standard color package options like dvipsnames and svgnames are doing @Bulldrive

Yes, but I seem to remember that it is not suggested to enable all the named colours.

I would like to have a single package that will handle the various palettes.  What implementation structure would that look like ?

@Bulldrive as I say look at how xcolor defines palettes such as "html color names" or "svg color names" I am sure we have been through this all before but you choose to make finding old answers hard by changing your account name repeatedly.

It is se that makes it hard to keep using an account.

Have looked at the xcolor code (xcolor.dtx) and it it difficult to read and implement similar.  Also I am using html colour versions.

Is it acceptable to have dashes in colour names defined with \definecolor ?

why would I have posted an answer that was not acceptable?
